# saving / printing to html or pdf for shiny apps with r charts

Tags: r, printing, pdf-generation, rcharts, shiny

I made a shiny app with rcharts, and now I'd like to be able to save the reports generated - I've found that printing shiny apps to pdf or html generally is a pretty good way to save reports generated with shiny apps. This way I get to see the whole app, and I find it preferable to downloading each chart separately. However, when there are rcharts involved, the printed charts have big black dots for every point:[image]

Does anyone know of a good way to save rcharts? I have tried paperless printer - http://www.rarefind.com/paperlessprinter/